# natbib's merge functionality in the appendix

Tags: bibtex, natbib, appendices

The `natbib` package has a very useful option `merge` that allows one to have two or more references under the same number.
If works fine for the following simple code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,english]{article}
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{References.bib}
@article{Book1,
    author = {M.~G. Author and T.~K. Author},
    journal = {J. Opt. Soc. Am. A},
    number = {7},
    pages = {811--818},
    title = {Article Title1},
    volume = {71},
    year = {1981}
}
@article{Book2,
    author = {M.~G. Author and T.~K. Author},
    journal = {J. Opt. Soc. Am.},
    number = {17},
    pages = {811--818},
    title = {Article Title1},
    volume = {11},
    year = {1991}
}

\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[numbers, merge]{natbib}

\begin{document}

   \cite{Book1, *Book2} %note merging "*" here (result: [1])

   \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
   \bibliography{References}
\end{document}
```

But once I want to merge references after `\thebibliography` command (say, in the appendix) it does not work:

```
\begin{document}

   \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
   \bibliography{References} %my *.bib file

   \cite{Book1, *Book2} %(result: [1,2])

\end{document}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you provide us with your `References.bib` file as well?

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: I am unable to replicate the problem you report getting: in both cases, I get `[1]` as the citation call-out.